# Solving $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{x f(x)}{1+ax}\,\mathrm dx=0$ for $a$

Tags: real-analysis, probability-distributions

I need to find  $a$ in terms of the function $f$ subject to

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{x f(x)}{1+ax} \,\mathrm{d}x = 0,$$

where $f(x)$ is a some given probability density function usually concentrated near $x=0$ and $f(x) = 0$ for $x\leqslant-\dfrac{1}{a}$.

By expanding $\dfrac{x}{1+ax}$ around $x=0$, I get

$$a=\frac{\sum\limits_{i=0}^\infty a^{2i}E[X^{2i+1}]}{\sum\limits_{i=0}^\infty a^{2i}E[X^{2i+2}]},$$

which (under the conditions) yields a useful rough approximation:

$$a\approx \frac{\mu_X}{\sigma_X^2}.$$

An exact expression giving $a$ in terms of some integral using $f$ would be first prize, but any insights/comments/advice would be appreciated.